# How to do insert into table in if and else condition of triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
create trigger thequery4 
on employees
instead of insert, delete
as
    declare @var3 int

    select @var3 = d.D_ID  
    from inserted d, DEPARTMENTS dp 
    where d.D_ID = dp.D_ID

    if (@var3 is null)
    begin
        print 'you are NOT  allowed , B/C IS Its d_Id is not present in department '
    end
    else
    begin
        ---- insert ----
    end
```

Comment: It is as same as normal insertion. there is no magic

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged.

Comment: Also a trigger can affect multiple rows, this assumes just one. And you declare it for DELETE as well as INSERT but the INSERTED table will be empty in the delete case

Comment: looks like you need a foreign key for this not a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin Smith suggested in comments section that you really need a foreign key constraint between the two tables. However, a trigger to handle this would look something like...

```
CREATE TRIGGER thequery4 
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM inserted i
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                                    FROM DEPARTMENTS dp WHERE  i.D_ID = dp.D_ID))
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'you are NOT  allowed , B/C IS Its d_Id is not present in department '
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            ---- insert ----
        END
END
```

Comment: 1 thing more, bro..syntax of insert in else portion..??  like .. generic insertion

Comment: @ZarrarNiazi yes.